# Difference between current time and other time in database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to run a mysql query in php so that it would delete all the rows where the difference between the current time and a date stored in the date_time column is bigger than 2 days.
I am trying to do this.

```
$query="DELETE FROM fomrad_requests WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date_time,now())>=2*24*60*60";
    $conn->query($query);
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Why you should be doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Dawid Ferenczy , I replied to Gordon's answer, saying that I saw after posting that the code works. I just inserted the wrong database name. Sorry, guys...

Comment: I meant something different - you were asking what are you doing wrong. But you didn't describe, what didn't work, what errors did you get etc. This way nobody is able to help you, since nobody know, what do you need to help with. BTW if you have used wrong DB name, error message had to be "DB xyz doesn't exist", so it had to be obvious, wasn't it? Anyway, I'm glad you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something simpler, such as this?

```
delete fr
    from fomrad_requests fr
    where date_time <= date_sub(now(), interval 2 day);
```

Comment: or `where date_time <= now() - interval 2 day;`

Comment: @Dagon . . . I get nervous about using `now()` in expressions like that.  It really isn't a `datetime`.  It is a string or number depending on the context.

Comment: ok I'll never do it again. :-) Actually having read some of the stuff you have written i would always bow to your wisdom on such matters

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , your answer works. But, at a further check, I saw that mine works too. I only used a wrong datatable name... Such a shame. Anyway thanks for your answer and sorry for asking this.. :(